# Can I use Facebook advertising for an iOS app without having the SDK integrated?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, ads

I have my app already sent for App Store review few days ago. I just noticed that Facebook advertising requires the Facebook SDK to be integrated with the app. Is it a compulsory step? Or can I use Facebook advertising without having the Facebook SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Facebook

Can I run mobile app ads without using the SDK?

Yes, we allow anyone to run mobile app install ads from our Ads Create Tool simply by dropping the link to their Apple App Store or Google Play URL. For mobile app engagement ads, you will need to register your app, but can also run ads without the SDK.

However, without installing and using the SDK, Facebook will not be able to provide install or app event reporting, and thus you will not have the option to use more advanced bidding options (oCPM, CPA) or see performance beyond clicks.